# Recent apps window doesn't show up when using Google Now Launcher but works well for stock launcher

Tags: launcher, oppo-find-7

I have a Oppo Find 7 phone running Lollipop.

Since I don't really like ColorOS launcher, I decided to download **Google Now Launcher** from Play Store and set it as **default launcher**.

It works perfectly, except for the fact that neither of the hardware keys (not even while long-pressing) shows the recent apps window (i.e. where to close recently opened apps).

Is it normal? **Is there any workaround?**

Comment: You mean recent apps key is not working? Which version of Android do you use?

Comment: Does your Android not have an option to configure buttons under Settings? Also, are you to open to app-based solutions?

Comment: yes, I'm opened to any app-based solution.
recentapps key is working on stock launcher but not on Google app launcher (or I don't know how to use it).
No button customization as far as I see

Comment: Please use @ followed by the name of person who you want to notify. Anyhow, is the device rooted?

Comment: @dragonmnl I guess Google Now Launcher is not fully supported for your phone. Can you try Apex Launcher or Nova Launcher and see if that works for you.

Comment: finally it was a bug of ColorOS. updating to latest beta solved it

Comment: Did you find any reference that it's indeed a bug? Also, for the sake of completeness, did you just buy the phone fresh from the box (not second hand)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a bug in ColorOS. Updating to latest beta (2.1.4i) solved it.  Betas can be downloaded from [the OPPO forums](http://community.oppo.com/en/threads-40-1.html) and flashed like any other ROM package.